# Error when adding SSL certificate for WebSite binding in IIS

Tags: iis, https, ssl-certificate

When I try to add https binding for my site in IIS I select Binding menu, then certificate that I want to use from drop down list and after I click OK I got an error

> Error during operation -  A device attached to the system is not functioning (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)

I've tried different certificates also checked that private keys are exportable

For IIS Host I use Windows 10 Pro 1803 and IIS 10.0.17763.1

**UPDATE 1**

I've also tried adding SSL certificate with

```
netsh http add sslcert 127.0.0.1:8035 certhash=hash appid={guid fo appid}
```

This approach also returned an error

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 31 A device attached to the system
>   is not functioning

Comment: To trigger a more meaningful error message, you might need to learn and use `netsh`. (like `netsh http show sslcert`).

Comment: @LexLi i've updated description with `netsh` result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated cryptography service provider (CryptoPro CSP in my case) for a newer version and rebooted the system and error magically gone away

Comment: How did you figure out it was CryptoPro? Updating it solved both my problem with IIS Express AND the broken CosmosDB emulator! I've wasted about 3 days on fighting with this and didn't get nowhere near solving it. Finally read a suggestion to try `netsh http add sslcert` manually and that's when I got the `A device is not functioning` nonsense which led me to this page! A billion upvotes to you, sir!

Comment: Ridiculous. Only unistalling VipNET solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with CryptoPro CSP v4.0.9944. As a consequence, was forced to delete CryptoPro CSP, choose certificate in IIS and install again.